# Get soled Products with counter in Magento

Tags: orders, products, sales-order, grid

I want to get all the products that are sold also with counter like if product1 with 3 (times soled ).I am trying code like this one :

```
$itemsCollection= Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
    ->join('order', 'order_id=entity_id');
```

But How can i get the product counter with that ?
My Grid Class method code :

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
  {
    $itemsCollection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    $itemsCollection= Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
    ->join('order', 'order_id=entity_id');

$itemsCollection->addExpressionFieldToSelect("total_sold" , 'SUM({{qty_ordered}} - {{qty_canceled}})',array("qty_ordered" => "qty_ordered",
                "qty_canceled" => "qty_canceled"));

$itemsCollection = $itemsCollection->getSelect()->group("product_id");
      $this->setCollection($itemsCollection);
      return parent::_prepareCollection();
  }
```

Now i got `Unrecognized method 'setPageSize()'` Error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested by here we go

```
// Your code
$itemsCollection= Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
    ->join('order', 'order_id=entity_id');

// sum qty ordered - the canceled qty as it's not really sold if it's canceled. 
// refunded also is debatable
$itemsCollection->addExpressionFieldToSelect("total_sold" , 'SUM({{qty_ordered}} - {{qty_canceled}})',array("qty_ordered" => "qty_ordered",
                "qty_canceled" => "qty_canceled"));

$itemsCollection->getSelect()->group("product_id"); // make sure we group
```

You will then be able to loop thought the collection and get the total qty per product

```
foreach($itemsCollection as $item){
            $totalSold = $item->getTotalSold();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your message.I tried your query but i got this error .`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '{qty_ordered - qty_canceled}}) AS `total_sold` FROM `sales_flat_order_item` AS `' at line 1
`.

Comment: Sorry typo. Have corrected

Comment: Thanks its works but i got another issue on Grid page using above query `Unrecognized method 'setPageSize()' `.What i am missing ? I have add my new code in question.

Comment: Are you setting the $collection = $collection->getSelect()->group("product_id"); in your prepareCollection method

Comment: Yes you can see my code on question.I already put updated code there.

Comment: Change $itemsCollection = $itemsCollection->getSelect()->group("product_id"); to $itemsCollection->getSelect()->group("product_id");